# New installation of TexLive 2023, PATH setting problem under Windows 11

Tags: texlive, paths

I thought the new installation of TeXLive 2023 seemed to have set everything needed, but I have discovered a problem with the systems path variable. I worked before with TeXLive 2022 and now both path settings (for 2022 and 2023) are shown with the informative path command.

The problem arises since my running of tex4ebook showed that it is directed to the TeXLive 2022 installation and not the new one of 2023, which I need to get out of an error.

I looked up in the path setting of Win11 and removed the bin path for TeXLive 2022, started the computer anew, found that it is now not shown in the menu for path settings under Win11. But when I go to the TeX command line and look for the PATH variables, the path for TeXLive 2022 is still there.

Do I need to remove TeXLive 2022? Will this remove the path and get me access to TexLive 2023?

Comment: Does your Windows 11 have both administrator PATH, and per-user PATH?

Comment: Yes, both is available. But meanwhile I decided to uninstall TexLive 2022, which removed the path for texlive bin 2022 and the run of my tex programms like tex4ebook now use the TeXLive 2023 bins and path variables. This problems seems in this manner to be solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try run `where tex` on cmd. If TeX Live 2022 is in front of 2023. You should remove the path of 2022 from environment variables. Or just unistall TeX Live 2022 if you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you, Clara. This has been my task. Both bin path will be shown and 2022 at first. I tried to find out how I can remove bin path 2022, but from cmd this seems to give differences between temporarily and permanent removing.  I also got the message that access was denied though I am logged in as administrator. - And why is there a difference between cmd showing of path and the path setting in Win11? I deleted there the bin path for texlive 2022, but on cmd it remained.

Comment: Maybe some in user variables or system variables. You can run `path` on cmd to see all paths.

Comment: Yes, please see comment of mine above. I uninstalled TeXLive 2022. No it works in this case. But my question above remains.